# Pattern for Google Alerts-style service

Tags: email, parse-platform, alerts, google-alerts

I'm building an application that is constantly collecting data. I want to provide a customizable alerts system for users where they can specify parameters for the types of information they want to be notified about. On top of that, I'd like the user to be able to specify the frequency of alerts (as they come in, daily digest, weekly digest).

Are there any best practices or guides on this topic?

My instincts tell me queues and workers will be involved, but I'm not exactly sure how.

I'm using Parse.com as my database and will also likely index everything with Lucene-style search. So that opens up the possibility of a user specifying a query string to specify what alerts s/he wants.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Rails and Heroku and Parse, we've done something similar. We actually created a second Heroku app that did not have a web dyno -- it just has a worker dyno. That one can still access the same Parse.com account and runs all of its tasks in a rake task like they specify here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler#defining-tasks

We have a few classes that can handle the heavy lifting:

```
class EmailWorker
  def self.send_daily_emails
    # queries Parse for what it needs, loops through, sends emails
  end
end
```

We also have the scheduler.rake in lib/tasks:

```
require 'parse-ruby-client'
task :send_daily_emails => :environment do
  EmailWorker.send_daily_emails
end
```

Our scheduler panel in Heroku is something like this:

```
rake send_daily_emails
```

We set it to run every night. Note that the public-facing Heroku web app doesn't do this work but rather the "scheduler" version. You just need to make sure you push to both every time you update your code. This way it's free, but if you ever wanted to combine them it's simple as they're the same code base.

You can also test it by running `heroku run rake send_daily_emails` from your dev machine.

Comment: You should be using IronWorker for stuff like this. Way cheaper, better performing, and more flexible. I can help with this.

Comment: Looks interesting. Cheaper than free, though? :)

Comment: Iron.io has a generous free plan. And if you go over the tier, it's way cheaper than paying for a monthly Heroku dyno. Pay as you go...

Comment: Only problem is that it doesn't have access to my Rails models & whatnot, so I'd have to build out some mini-apps to handle what I want to do. At this point, not worth it, but something to consider if we have scaling issues.